# create a Pandas DataFrame column based on over 9 filter of the existing columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, np

I am making a column based the filtering of existing column. And shown below is my code. I wondering whether there is a better way to make it simple. My pandas dataframe is quite big and I want to filter and create a new columns. Any help will be highly appreciated. Not that the functions inside the np.where is defined separately.

```
 def standard_price(load):
        '''
        setting the consignment price
        standard price
        '''
        m1 = load['p'] == 1
        m2 = load['p'] == 2
        m3 = load['p'] == 3
        m4 = load['p'] == 4
        m5 = load['p'] == 5
        m6 = load['p'] == 6
        m7 = load['p'] == 7
        m8 = load['p'] == 8
        m9 = load['p'] == 9
        load['price'] = np.where(m1, k(load),
                                          np.where(m2, m(load),
                                                   np.where(m3, n(load),
                                                            np.where(m4, chuden_sp(load),
                                                                     np.p(m5, p(load),
                                                                              np.k(m6, b(load),
                                                                                       np.where(m7, e(load),
                                                                                                np.where(m8, q(load),
                                                                                                         np.where(m9, a(load), 'no match')))))))))
return load['price']
```

Comment: Did my suggested answer work?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `map`:

```
load['price'] = load['p'].map({
    1: k(load),
    2: m(load),
    ...
}).fillna('no_match')
```